# How MandelbrotSetBoettcher function is computed?

Tags: equation-solving, complex, fractals

Boettcher function is a solution of [Boettcher's functional equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%B6ttcher%27s_equation), so in case of [complex quadratic map](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/QuadraticMap.html):

$B(f(z)) = (B(z))^2$

where:

- B is Boettchers function
- f is [complex quadratic map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_quadratic_polynomial)

There is a function [MandelbrotSetBoettcher](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MandelbrotSetBoettcher.html) in Mathematica.

What algorithm is used in MandelbrotSetBoettcher ?

------ Edit ----------------

I can use [lab](https://lab.wolframcloud.com/app/objects/11b62877-3242-41e1-8386-6b3a4e8fa646) to see internal code. ( way from code to algorithm is hard)

At the end is :

```
MandelbrotSetBoettcher[___][___] :=kernel function
```

Does it mean that code is protected ?

Comment: You can see the internal code that computes the map by running  ``Get["GeneralUtilities`"]; PrintDefinitions[MandelbrotSetBoettcher]``.

Comment: Did you find the definition of ` ```System`FractalSetsBoettcherDump`cfMandelbrotSetBoettcher` ```when looking at the internal code?

Comment: no, only :MandelbrotSetBoettcher[z:Alternatives[_Complex,_Real,PatternTest[_, Function[ArrayQ[#, _, InexactNumberQ]]]],opts ....